# GXT Grid ListStore - get unmodified Records

Tags: extjs, gxt

I have a Grid whch allows a user to update columns (i.e. properties in a ModelData).
Is there a way for me to see the un-modified record (i.e. ModelData)?

When the user clicks a 'Commit' button:
I can use ***List modifiedRecords = listStore.getModifiedRecords();*** for modified records.
I can use ***Map changedFieldsMap = modifiedRecord.getChanges();*** to see the columns that have changed but I can't see what the unchanged values are...  can I?!?!

~richard

Answer (score 1):

friend if u can get a list of modified record then u can easily retrieve a list of unmodified record by creating a new dummy store and just remove the modified records from that its so simple by fighting with a single loop and some conditions.

Comment: Yeah...  that would work; seems a bit clumsy though.  I spent a bit of time looking through the GXT code starting with com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.store.Store .commitChanges().   (it gets a little complicated and I’m in a bit of a rush…  as usual  ;-).  I was just wondering if there was an API call I was missing of something easy.

Thanx for the response.